# Bash create custom string

Tags: bash, format, perl, regex

how could in bash a pattern like

```
ROW1   n1    n2    n3   n4
```

up to 300 be done with some command in `bash` or also just `perl`...the delimiter would need to be `\t`

as above

Answer (score 9):

You can use brace expansion and `printf`:

```
printf "%s\t" ROW1 n{1..300}
```

The first string specifies the format of output to `printf`, and `%s` is replaced with a corresponding argument. Since there is only `%s`, `printf` will re-use the format specifier until all arguments are exhausted. This will leave a trailing tab.

`{1..300}` is bash syntax which expands into numbers from 1 to 300, separated by spaces. If a string is added before or after the braces, the expanded form will also have that string attached.

To avoid a trailing tab, you'll have to print something separately, either the first word, or the last:

```
printf "ROW1"; printf "\tn%d" {1..300}
printf "%s\t" ROW1 n{1..299}; echo n300
```

Answer (score 3):

Simpler command:

```
echo -n "ROW1" && echo -ne "\t"n{1..300}
```

Even simpler thanks to [@hildred](https://askubuntu.com/users/216190/hildred)

```
echo -ne "ROW1" "\t"n{1..300}
```

Comment: even simpler: `echo -ne "ROW1"  "\t"n{1..300}`

Answer (score 0):

In a one-liner:

```
echo -n "ROW1"; for ((i=1; i<=300; i++)); do echo -ne "\t n${i}"; done
```

Or using the same approach using brace expansion (thanks to A.B. for the suggestion):

```
echo -n "ROW1"; for i in {1..300}; do echo -ne "\t n${i}"; done
```

Comment: `echo -n "ROW1"; for n in {1..300}; do echo -ne "\t n$n"; done` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Because you mentioned `perl`

```
perl -e 'printf "ROW1"; printf "\tn%d",$_ foreach (1..300)'
```