# get rid of character

Tags: text-processing

```
printf "%s\t" Nt n{1..1600} >file_a
printf "%s\t" R cha 2 987 > file_aa
awk '{print}' file_a file_aa > newfile
```

to creat a file in which the header looks like

```
Nt /t n1 /t n2 /t n3 ....
```

the problem is that when lookin at how this prints it turns out that in the last n it is

```
\t   n   1   5   9   8  \t   n   1   5   9   9  \t   n   1   6
0   0  \t  \n
```

so there is something after nt 1600 - how can I lose this last `\t` in awk? Or somewhere?

I was talking about the last `\t` in that `\t n 1 5 9 8 \t n 1 5 9 9 \t n 1 6 0 0 \t \n` here - I need the newline character - both answers did not solve that.

I do need

```
printf "%s\t" Nt n{1..1600} >file_a
printf "%s\t" R cha 2 987 > file_aa
```

There has to be a newline.

Comment: What is the 0002120 and 0002130 at the beginning of the lines?

Comment: @A.B. output of  `od -c`. `od` adds those to help track byte counts.

Comment: Or alternatively, you could **visit the answers to your previous questions** and notice that all of the answers at http://askubuntu.com/questions/640854/ gave you ways to generate this stuff without the trailing tab character *in the first place*.  Several people on several of your questions have now asked you to look at the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are talking about `\n`, if you don't want that newline to appear, use `cat` to join those files instead of awk:

```
cat file_a file_aa > newfile
```

The difference:

```
$ awk 1  <(printf "%d\t" {1..2} ) <(printf "%d\t" {1..2} )
1   2   
1   2   
$ cat <(printf "%d\t" {1..2} ) <(printf "%d\t" {1..2} )
1   2   1   2
```

---

Since you want to delete the trailing `\t`, try:

```
sed -i 's/\t*$//' file_a
awk '{print}' file_a file_aa
```

- `\t*$` is any number of tabs at the end of the line `$`.

The effect:

```
$ awk 1 <(printf "%d\t" {1..2} | sed 's/\t*$//') <(printf "%d\t" {1..2} ) | od -c              
0000000   1  \t   2  \n   1  \t   2  \t  \n
0000011
```

Comment: no I was taking about the last /t in that swe \t n 1 5 9 8 \t n 1 5 9 9 \t n 1 6 0 0 \t \n here - i need the newline character

Comment: @user3069326 see update.

Answer (score 1):

The tab is there because you are adding it:

```
printf "%s\t"
```

That will print every string you give it followed by a tab. So, the last string will have a tab after it as well. To avoid that, you could either remove it after creating it using `sed` or similar tools (see @muru's[answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/642292/85695)), or you can use a different tool to create it. For example, 
`perl`:

```
perl -le 'print "NT\tn", join("\tn",(1..1600)), "\nR\tcha\t2\t987\n"' > newfile
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need a newline, just add one

```
{ printf "%s\t" Nt n{1..1600}; echo; } > file_a
{ printf "%s\t" R cha 2 987;   echo; } > file_aa
sed 's/\t$//'  file_a file_aa          > newfile
```

Or, without the temp files:

```
{ 
    printf "%s\t" Nt n{1..1600}; echo
    printf "%s\t" R cha 2 987;   echo
} | sed 's/\t$//' > newfile
```

Or, without having to explicitly remove the trailing tabs:

```
(                    # in a subshell, so IFS is not modified in the current shell
    IFS=$'\t'
    head1=( Nt n{1..1600} ); echo "${head1[*]}"
    head2=( R cha 2 987 );   echo "${head2[*]}"
) > newfile
```