# get a tab out of a vector

Tags: bash, sed, regex

if I have the first line of my file looking like this

```
NAMES           n1  n2  n3
```

betwen row1 and t1 there are two tabs but there should only be a single tab...the line is in a larger file it is always in the first line. How can I delete the tab too much between ROW1 and the first entry afterwards like

```
NAMES   n1  n2  n3
```

Comment: What does the rest of the file contain?

Comment: Is it the output of the procedures given in the several answers at http://askubuntu.com/questions/640854/ ?  You've done something wrong, if so.  Did you read the advice at http://askubuntu.com/questions/642289/ about reading the answers to your questions?

Answer (score 1):

Using `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/^(\w*)\t\t/$1\t/' <your_input_file>
```

Add the `-i` switch for inline replace

```
perl -i -pe 's/^(\w*)\t\t/$1\t/' <your_input_file>
```

To replace all `\t\t`, not only between the 1st and the 2nd column, use

```
perl -i -pe 's/\t\t/\t/' foo
```

or to replace all `\t` with a count greater than 1

```
perl -i -pe 's/\t{2,}/\t/g' foo
```

---

*Example*

```
$ printf "%s\t\t%s %s\n" "foo" "bar" "foobar" > foo
$ perl -i -pe 's/^(\w*)\t\t/$1\t/' foo
$ cat foo
foo     bar foobar
```

or with your example:

```
$ printf "%s\t\t%s %s %s\n" "ROW1" "t1" "t2" "t3" > foo
$ perl -i -pe 's/^(\w*)\t\t/$1\t/' foo
$ cat foo
ROW1    t1 t2 t3
```

Comment: somh that doesnt work for me...i still have two tabs between row and n1

Comment: with sed or perl?

Comment: the sed option...the first thing is not called t1 it is n1...confused it...but i tried sed 's/^(\w*)\t\n/$1\t/' foo

Comment: Use the perl version with the better regex engine

Comment: just tried that assume the t1 is a n1 then i used 
NAMES           n1 n2 n3 
perl -pe 's/^(\w*)\t\n/$1\t/' trf

Comment: also changed...above i did get thw wrong line but there should not be much of a differen except for the n?

Comment: you need only `'s/^(\w*)\t\t/$1\t/'` not more